# Same table one to many on delete cascade

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, one-to-many

In my .NET Core app I have a commenting system where you can reply to a comment and those replies can also be replied to. the replies and comments are all of type `Comment`. I want all child replies to be deleted when a parent is deleted. I however can't figure out how to configure this.

This is how my last migration looks which was meant to set on delete cascade:

```cs
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Comments_Comments_ParentId",
                table: "Comments");

            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Comments_Comments_ParentId",
                table: "Comments",
                column: "ParentId",
                principalTable: "Comments",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        }
```

Running this migration throws:

`Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Comments_Comments_ParentId' on table 'Comments' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.`

Comment.cs:

```cs
    public class Comment {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int MemeId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; } = new HashSet<Comment>();
        public Comment Parent { get; set; }
    }
```

`OnModelCreation()` in context:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {
            builder.Entity<Comment>()
                .HasOne(c => c.Parent)
                .WithMany("Comments")
                .HasForeignKey("ParentId")
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
```

Comment: not sure `entity framework core` can handle cascade delete on self referencing table. Might have to handle manually  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37936221/how-to-set-on-delete-cascade-for-self-reference-foreign-key-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 0):

No need to handle manually. You can add the Cascade Behavior to your entities as below. 
inside OnModelCreating;

```
foreach (var foreignKey in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
            {
                foreignKey.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Cascade;
            }
```

[image]